# Puppeteer: can't resolve waitForFunction - possibly js files not loaded

Tags: puppeteer

When I launch Puppeter with Tor proxy like `'--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'`, then it often don't resolve `waitForFunction` in `headless: true` mode. Seems like it never load js files.
Does somebody know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try adding these options

```
{
  timeout: 0,
  waitUntil: ["domcontentloaded", "networkidle0"]
}
```

to the page.goto() statement

you can check the [docs here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.11.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options)

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't solve the problem. There are two kind of cases: js files are loaded pretty quick or never.

Comment: @krzyhub try to put some console.log to see where it stops, use headless: false to see visually what is happening in the browser

Comment: I spent long time debbuging it and I gave up at the end. Possibly the issue in my case is caused by blocking some pool of countries ips by the server that hosts page I am visiting.